# Function takes no arguments(1 given)

Tags: python, perforce

I am running python 2.7 on Windows.  I've got a simple config file that connects to a Perforce server. When I try to connect the Perforce server Python complains that I am passing an argument to a function that takes no argument.  I am familiar with `self` being passed as the first argument to a class function but this is not happening in my code.  Here is the relevant section of code:

```
from P4 import P4

p4 = P4()
p4.user = 'myuser'
p4.port = 'myport:1666'
p4.password = 'SUP3RS3CR3TP4SSW0RD'

p4.connect()
```

which fails with a `TypeError: connect() takes no arguments (1 given)`

The code was developed on OS X and is running on a Windows machine. If I run the same code in the Python REPL it works fine.  Only when it is imported in my project does this `TypeError` occur.

Any idea what is going on?  (The code worked as is last time I ran it)

Comment: please show the code where the `connect` method is defined.

Comment: P4 is Python bindings to the Official Perforce API library.  I didn't actually implement P4.connect().

Comment: In your question you have `p4.connect()` and in your comment you have `P4.connect()` which (capitalization) is it? The code in the question appears to be fine as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by deleting my entire branch and re-syncing to perforce.  I assume the data inside some of the files must have been corrupted and somehow p4.connect() was actually passing some garbage argument not visible to me in Sublime Text.